# What does agent.maxSockets really mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, websocket

The official [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) on agent.maxSockets says that it indicates the limit on how many concurrent sockets my http(s) server can have. So I did some tests with `http.globalAgent.maxSockets set to 5` and I expected that I can have only 5 open websockets. But turns out I can have more than 50 open websockets.
 Can anybody explain what does agent.maxSockets really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.Agent` instances are used with *outbound* http clients (e.g. via `http.request()`), *not inbound* clients into an `http.Server`. So if you were to use an `http.Agent` with `maxSockets` set to 5 with `http.request()`, then there would only be at most 5 connected sockets to a particular server at any given time.

Comment: So this is used when I am creating a client not a server, I see. But how then I would set the number of maxConnections to the server? If I would use the net module to create the server, it would be `this.maxConnections` inside the function that handles requests. But how can I set this if I am to use the http module?

Comment: I guess `this.maxConnection` would work equally well for the http module since it's just a wrapper around the net module.